# Mono.TextTemplating passing parameters to template

Tags: c#, monodevelop, t4, css, texttemplate

I try to pass a parameter(foo) to an existing template(MyTemplate.tt) with this command:

**TextTransform.exe -a=foo!bar -o Output.txt MyTemplate.tt**

MyTemplate.tt:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>

<#
  this.Write(foo);  
#>
```

This command fails due to the parameter "foo" is not existing.
How can I pass this parameter correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments of MonoDevelop's TextTransform.exe match Microsoft's, which are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126245.aspx).

Unfortunately, these parameters are not exposed as as variables in code, they are intended as arguments for custom directive processors. To access them directly from code you must set `hostspecific="true"` and access them via `Host.ResolveParameterValue (paramName)`.

You could however use dynamic objects to make your example work, by [implementing `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff800651.aspx) on your template's base class and overriding `BindGetMember` to resolve parameters from `Host.ResolveParameterValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this works fine for me:

**TextTransform.exe -a=foo!bar -o Output.txt MyTemplate.tt**

MyTemplate.tt:

```
<#@ template language="C#" hostspecific="true" #>
<# string temp = this.Host.ResolveParameterValue("", "", "foo");#>
<#
  this.Write(temp);  
#>
```

Output.txt:

```
bar
```

I will have also a look at IDynamicMetaObjectProvider.